# Table Lua checks names

Tags: lua, lua-table

Now, I have a list that stores the names of "moderators."

`moderator = { ["user1"] = true, ["user2"] = true, ["user3"] = true }`

I want that if the user is moderator (if his name is in the list), he will be able to add other names in the list (that is, make other users moderators)

Answer (score 0):

```
moderators = { ["user1"] = true, ["user2"] = true, ["user3"] = true }
```

Create a function to check if someone is a moderator:

```
function isModerator(name)
    if moderators[name] == true then
        return true
    end

    return false
end
```

Then use it! If someone is a moderator, then allow them to add a new key-value pair to the `moderators` table:

```
if isModerator("user2") then
    moderators["otherName"] = true
end
```

Comment: There is no need to search the table of moderators. Just index it directly with the name.